# C# ?? operator difference

Tags: c#, if-statement, nullable

Is there a difference between the '?? true' and the '== true' within an if statement?

```
bool? b = Jsonfile.GetBoolean("testval");
if (b ?? true) { }
if (b == true) { }
```

Comment: Try it and find out. You only have three values to test.

Comment: "The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the right hand operand." from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx

Comment: @DirkVollmar maybe the lack of trying?

Comment: I assume the donvotes come from "this question does not show any research-effort". However you´re right: the question IS lgitimate, but of a low quality.

Comment: @DirkVollmar It shows a lack of effort.  You can write code to test the 6 possibilities in a few seconds.  Closing is what you would do if it were not legitimate.

Comment: @DirkVollmar As the others said, OP wrote some code himself right there and could compile it and see the differences. Additionally, googling something like `C# "??" operator / keyword"` would tell him exactly what it does. Presumably he's already familiar with `==`.

Comment: Actually `b ?? false` is the same as `b == true`.

Comment: thank you. So in my case - where i read from a json file - i should use `== true` on reading-in because null should equal false.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, there is.

`b ?? true` will match when `b` is `null` or `true`

`b == true` will match when `b` is not `null` and is `true`

The difference is in the first line of the table (when `b` is `null`)

```
b      b ?? true  b == true
====   ========== ==========
null   true       false
true   true       true
false  false      false
```

Answer (score 11):

Yes.

If `b` is null:

- `b == true` will return false.
- `b ?? true` will true.

Since `??` is the null-coalescing operator, it will only have effect when the left hand value is `null`. In this case, it does matter indeed.

As [juharr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/302918/juharr) commented on your question:

> `b ?? false` is the same as `b == true`

This is true, since `b.GetValueOrDefault()` returns `false`, which is actually the same as `?? false` in this case. If `b == null`, `b.GetValueOrDefault() == true` would yield `false`.

Comment: But `b ?? false` and `b == false` are different when `b` is not `null`

Comment: Indeed. That is just on the null case.

Comment: Yeah I though i'd point that out in case anyone got the wrong idea from what you were saying.

Comment: I will removed that since it doesn't add that much. I put your comment in though, which is a nice head-cracker.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/ms173224.aspx):

> The `??` operator returns the left-hand operand if it is not `null`, else, it returns the right-hand operand.